# CDI-like conversation scope in Spring

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I've been developing Spring 3 + JSF 2.0 applications for some time. They run on simple Tomcat or Jetty container. Looking ad CDI I envy a conversation scope.

Are you aware of simple conversation scope implementation for Spring? I don't want to use full-blown SpringMVC + WebFlow + SpringFaces stack. I just need a web filter that enables conversation scope and lets me inject conversation object and start or stop it. Like in CDI.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly on your question, but since you're asking for a solution in order to avoid using Spring Webflow, Spring Faces, etc ... it looks like you're using Spring just for DI (i mean you're not so dependent on the Spring ecosystem). Well, maybe in this case it would worth the effort to think about migrating to a Java EE 6 stack. I don't think the migration would be that difficult, since you're using not that much from Spring, and in case you have beans in spring you still need, you could write some CDI producers for them. You can google for some migration paths from Spring to Java EE 6.

And if you're afraid of the "heavy Java EE containers", well jboss 7.1, Glassfish 3.1.2 and TomEE all start on my notebook in under 2 seconds, and I bet  your tomcat + spring container don't start much faster.

Just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

you should give a look to Apache TomEE + CODI project (subject of Apache MyFaces) and/or Apache Deltaspike (not sure the doc is up to date because it is pretty young)

TomEE gives you the strength of CDI and CODI adds a small integration layer between cdi and jsf to make it very powerful (it will be integrated in deltaspike but that's still a bit in progress)

Answer (score 1):

MyFaces Orchestra (also works with Mojarra) is currently the best conversation scope implementation for JSF 2.0 on top of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSF `@ViewScoped` annotation on your managed bean that gives you the same conversation-like semantics as the CDI conversation scope. One difference between CDI's conversation scope and JSF's view scope is that CDI gives you explicit and straightforward control over the conversation while the JSF viewscope is pretty much canned for use. But with JSF's ViewScope, you know exactly where the boundaries of a conversation are: A conversation starts when you load a page backed with a `@ViewScoped` bean and ends when the page is closed. This is convenient for many use cases

Cagatay of primefaces also has [this hack](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0) to simulate the CDI scope in Spring.

[This tutorial](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/08/learning-jsf2-managed-beans/) by Max Katz from the the Richfaces team also gives a good intro the JSF ViewScope

Comment: Actually I am aware of view scope in Spring. I've used the Cagatay's one so far. Mind that view scope is kept in JSF's view root. So it is maintained on POST-backs and is refreshed on GET. Actually the difference - to span conversation across different pages and do not refresh it on page reload is something I need. And I don't want to use session scope for this.